# PHP api Need to make strings

Tags: php, arrays, exact-online, picqer-exact-php-client

I have a question about how I can give each output a single string.

**My code is:**

```
try {
    $journals = new \Picqer\Financials\Exact\Journal($connection);
    $result   = $journals->get();
    foreach ($result as $journal) {
        echo 'Journal: ' . $journal->Description . '<br>';
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo get_class($e) . ' : ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**and my output is:**

```
Journal: Kasboek 
Journal: Memoriaal
Journal: Activamutaties
Journal: Inkoopboek
Journal: Bank
Journal: Verkoopboek
```

I want all of the output in a different string so I can export it to my other site of the api. Something like this:

`Kasboek = $1 Memoriaal = $2 etc..`

Please help me to resolve this

**Journal.php**

```
<?php

namespace Picqer\Financials\Exact;

/**
 * Class Journal
 *
 * @package Picqer\Financials\Exact
 * @see https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=financialJournals
 *
 * @property String $Code BIC code of the bank where the bank account is held
 * @property Int32 $Division Division code
 * @property String $Description Description of BankAccount
 * @property Guid $ID Primary Key
 * @property String $Type Bank account number. Is mandatory for Journals that have Type = Bank
 */
class Journal extends Model
{
    use Query\Findable;
    use Persistance\Storable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'Code',
        'Division',
        'Description',
        'ID',
        'Type',
    ];

    protected $url = 'financial/Journals';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using an array or is there some constraint that forces you to use variables in the format `$1`, `$2`, etc.?

Comment: In the other side of the api I can create something whit $1 "word" and that is the way I need to add it.

Comment: If this is an API you should consider using something like JSON format to present values to the application calls this endpoint for data.

Comment: ^ Agreed. Creating your own data format will most likely not only come back and bite you, but every one that would use the API would need to write a custom parser. There's a reason why standards exist.

Comment: Btw, what are `$1` and `$2` in your expected response? Is it some id, index or something else?

Comment: @PraveenM I think you have misunderstood me. I want to import data from the one to the other. like I make a support tick on side 1 and that support ticket needs to be on side 2. so if I dont do it like this all of the data is in one ticket if you unstand what I mean. Or dit i misunderstood you?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson $1 and $2 need to represent a string that is filled already.

Comment: Then your question should contain that as well. You're asking us how to create a result (in a format we already recommended against) but you're not giving us all the pieces.

Answer (score 2):

When you use **api**. You really should convert your output into `json` or `xml`. So from any language you can read it. Change your code as below

```
try {
    $result = array();
    $journals = new \Picqer\Financials\Exact\Journal($connection);
    $result   = $journals->get();
    foreach ($result as $journal) {
       $result[]= $journal->Description;
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(array(get_class($e) . ' : ' . $e->getMessage()));
}
```

Comment: **If I do that i get a to much detailed ouput that i dont want** {"Code":"70","Description":"Verkoopboek","Division":1741496,"ID":"b4afe081-7f6b-46c7-9742-ea22302a4d55","Type":20},"Kasboek","Memoriaal","Activamutaties","Inkoopboek","Bank","Verkoopboek"]`

Comment: @RikEdsas Will you please stop bolding ordinary text? In written text, it's kind of like screaming. I've already reformatted your question to remove all the bold, but I can't reformat your comments.

Comment: @RikEdsas check code properly if you only add `$journal->Description;` then other data must not be append

Comment: @B.Desai I think I see what that problem is causing... I will add a new script  on my question so u can see it. What i don't understand is that whe call for Description and that we get all of the table's.